# Why isn't installing executable file (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I need to install the apk file. I follow the instructions - "adb install" and the name of the file you want to install. I get a message that there is no such file ...

[image]

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing `sudo`.

Comment: I think you have to copy the apk onto the Android device, then give the full path of the apk. `adb install` isn't looking at your local filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you enabled USB debugging on your Android Device?**

---

If not:

- Go to settings
- Go to about phone
- Find build number
- Repeatedly tap the build number, until it says you are now a developer or something along those lines
- Back to main settings page
- Find developer options
- Allow USB debugging

---

**A link to help**

---

Also check out | [How To Geek - ADB](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/)

Hope I Helped!

Comment: You may also need the driver, typically available on the manufacturers website.